# Improve website speed defer JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

i am having troubles with defer and async js files.
My website is loading JQuery and Jquery-UI libraries and they are kind of big files even .min files
When i am moving those libraries to the bottom of website or just defering - asyncing them, my website stops rendering most of elements, for example

- Select2 plugin not working properly on mobile phones
- Jquery range slider not dragging
- Some other custom elements like infinite load are not working as well

So i am trying to improve my website speed, but those 2 libraries render blockers and with them i got only 53 rating on PageSpeed Insights.

So another way to make Website run faster is merging(combine) JS files, but after combine website stops rendering also, so i guess only some of them are able to be combined. 
Can someone help me resolve this problem ? below i will give a list of all JS that is used on my website

```
jquery-2.1.1.min.js
greensock.js
layerslider.transitions.js (actually trying to find some lightweight alternative)
layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js
jquery-ui.min.js
jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js
select2.min.js
jquery.tooltipster.min.js
bootstrap.min.js
placeholders.js
jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
owl.carousel.min.js
html5shiv.js
```

**What i already did**

- Browser Caching - On
- GZip on the fly - On

  1. So and the main question is how to move jquery to the bottom without losing functionality
  2. Which libraries i am able to merge, to reduce HTTP requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @Dr.Web said you can also combine them into one file and make sure that the plugin code is added at the bottom of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Please note that using async let's the browser know that the script can be loaded asynchronously and not necessarily in order. This opens up issues when you are trying to load an async script that has multiple dependencies. In this case you should load the jQuery in your footer without async attribute and load the jQueryUI using async attribute.

Reference: [Source](http://www.neotechdesign.com/blog/how-to-speed-up-your-website)